# Spring Entity Manager Factory using JNDI

Tags: spring, jndi, entitymanager, jta

I am getting confused on how to get the entity Manager Factory in spring spring-datasource.xml using 
I did the following :

spring-datasource.xml file:

```
<tx:jta-transaction-manager id="transactionManager" />
<tx:annotation-driven mode="proxy"
transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManagerFactory" jndi-name="jdbc/mysqldatasource" />
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"      
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
           http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="ebankingUnit"
    transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/mysqldatasource</jta-data-source>
    <class>com.datamodel.Product</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO" />
        <property name="eclipselink.query-results-cache.expiry"
            value="5000" />
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

but I am getting thid

Answer (score 0):

which version of Spring are you using? You don't even need persistence.xml in the latest versions.

Here is the configuration using Spring 3.x, for oracle.

```
    <tx:annotation-driven/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- FactoryBean that creates the EntityManagerFactory -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="database" value="ORACLE" />
            <property name="showSql" value="false" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="blah.com..domain" />
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>


<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/myoracledb}" />
</bean>
```

Now define myoracledb jndi resource in your  web.xml

```
      <Resource name="myoracledb" auth="Container"
         type="javax.sql.DataSource"
         driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
         maxActive="50" 
          url="your db url"
          username="dbuser" password="dbpwd" />
```

Regards

Comment: Hi thanks for you help, but I want to use jndi from a weblogic datasource and JTA

Comment: I don't think it makes any difference, in weblogic create a Jndi resource and use the jndi name reference in datasource.